# what is the mean of question mark with variable name after the name of js file in src attribute of the script tag?

Tags: javascript

can any one explain for me what is the mean of question mark with variable name after the name of js file in src attribute of the script tag ?.

for example here

src="http://localhost/SamaJordan/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js **?ver=1.2.1** "

in the above example you can find this **?ver=1.2.1**.

we know that after php file name it is considered as a variable and we can get its value by using the super global array GET , but how can we take advantage of it when we send it after the javascript file name?

Comment: It's a query string in the file URL. It's used for cache busting (i.e. forcing the browser to download the new version instead of using the older, cached version of the file).

Comment: "after php file name it is consedered (sic!) a global variable" - what does that even mean? looks like someone needs to at least know what the technologies he uses are doing... (before attempting to *program* something, at least know how to *use* it.)

Comment: Sime Vidas thank you so much .

Comment: user3477950  I can't understand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To prevent the site from breaking during updates**. When whole site is updated including the JS files, users may end up using the new HTML but is still using the old js because the browser caches the files. If you add a unique identifier like "scripts?version=1.1" then it will be considered as a separate file and will use the new JS.